# How can I add classes or jars when connecting to an already existing Spark cluster?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, anonymous-function

I'm writing a program that accesses a Spark cluster as a client. It connects like this:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf(loadDefaults = false)
  .setMaster(sparkMasterEndpoint)
  .setAppName("foo")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandraHost)

  .setJars(Seq("target/scala-2.11/foo_2.11-1.0.jar"))
)
```

And that context is then used to run operations on Spark. However, any lambdas / anonymous functions I use in my code can't run on Spark. For example, I might have:

```
val groupsDescription = sc.someRDD()
  .groupBy(x => x.getSomeString())
  .map(x => x._1 + " " + x._2.count(_ => true))
```

This returns a lazily evaluated RDD, but when I try to extract some value from that RDD, I get this exception from Spark:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.app.Main$$anonfun$groupify$1$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1
```

Even though I've supplied my application's jar file to Spark. I even see a log line (in my application, not in my spark cluster) telling me the jar has been uploaded like this:

```
[info] o.a.s.SparkContext - Added JAR target/scala-2.11/foo_2.11-1.0.jar at spark://192.168.51.15:53575/jars/foo_2.11-1.0.jar with timestamp 1528320841157
```

I can find absolutely NOTHING on this subject anywhere, and it's driving me crazy! How has nobody else run in to this issue? All the related results I see are about bundling your jars for use with `spark-submit` which is not what I'm doing, I have a standalone application that's connecting to an independent spark cluster. Is this simply not supported? What else could I be missing? What else could be causing this?

Comment: What's the relationship between the code that throws the ClassNotFoundException and the jar? I don't see any? What makes you think the classes in the jar are not available on executors?

Comment: Sorry, I suppose that's not exactly accurate. More precisely, the code throws some kind of spark exception that wraps the ClassNotFoundException some layers down. The relationship to the jar is that this is supposedly a symptom of the executors not having access to the code they should, which I'm led to believe is why we have to upload the jar to them. I don't know a whole lot else about it, however. I've updated my question to fix this inaccuracy, and I'm going to set my project up again and rerun it to get the exact stack trace of errors wrapping that ClassNotFoundException in a sec.

Comment: Okay so NOW I'm getting a DIFFERENT ClassNotFoundException where the spark job doesn't even get out of the queue! I'm using this spark <-> cassandra connector and it looks like the connector jar is missing from my executors. Which would make sense, right? Except that I definitely did not include this connector jar earlier, so I'm pretty confused by what's going on. Ugh. I'm going to add it in my `setJars` as well and see what happens, I guess. [full stack trace if anyone wants it, but it's all wrapped in a bunch of nonsense. important bit on line 69.](https://pastebin.com/9irRrYKk)

Comment: Why do you use `setJars` not `--jars` or even bundling the entire dependency set into a single jar file?